# How to read/append string in C# with exact spacing/tabs/lines

Tags: c#, string, wysiwyg

I have sample data

```
string test = @"allprojects {
                    repositories {
                        test()
                    }
               }"
```

When I read the `test`, I should get the exact string with spaces/tabs/new lines instead of me writing `Environment.NewLine` etc wherever it requires new line. When I print, it should print the same format [WYSIWYG] type.

Presently it gives something like this in debugger  `allprojects {\r\n\t\t     repositories { \r\n\t\t         test() \r\n\t\t   } \r\n\t\t  }`

Comment: What's your issue? You can use `escape characters` for representing tabs and new lines in your code (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). .NET converts your new lines and tabs into escape characters also as you have mentioned in your last paragraph

Comment: Try "view in text visualizer", a small magnifier icon next to the variable text when you hover it in the debugger

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean "When I print"? (I assume you've already read enough answers talking about debugger showing encoded characters like double quotes and new  lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do in string literals that need this is just not indent the content at all:

```
namespace Foo {

    class Bar {

        const string test = @"
allprojects {
    repositories {
        test()
    }
}";

    }

}
```

And strip away the initial newline. Looks a bit ugly, but it does get the point across that the leading whitespace matters.

You can also place the `@"` on the second chance, but automatic code formatting could move that and it doesn't look as close to the actual text. (Code formatting should not touch the contents of a string, but I can't guarantee that.)

This should round-trip correctly if processing the string line-by-line, as would seem appropriate anyway:

```
var reader = new StringReader(test);
reader.ReadLine();

string line;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Or just read them from a file / resource.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to determine a new line, and it is dependant on the OS you are using:

- Windows: `\r\n`
- Unix: `\n`
- Mac: `\r`

As for a tab, all you need is `\t`.

Therefore, in your string all you need is:

```
string test = @"allprojects {\r\n\trepositories {\r\n\t\ttest()\r\n\t}\r\n}"
```

Which will output:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        test()
    }
}
```

Comment: i am aware of that. I am asking is there any utility/function, where I don't have to write `\r\n` etc instead I will just pass the original string, it should automatically go the magic.